# Bitbucket webhook to run jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

#### Update:

I succesfuly sent a post request from `curl` to trigger jenkins job:

```
curl -I -X POST http://jenkinsAccountUserName:jenkinsAccountPassword@JenkinsIp:8080/job/projecty_ci/build -H "Jenkins-Crumb:a4fb99fbdb252fda3cc69ee575bedabc"
```

I don't understand how to convert this to a url: `Problem accessing /job/projecty_ci/build. Reason: No valid crumb was included in the request`.

```
http://jenkinsAccountUserName:jenkinsAccountPassword@JenkinsIp:8080/job/projecty_ci/build?Jenkins-Crumb:a4fb99fbdb252fda3cc69ee575bedabc
```

this works fine from chrome but not from bitbucket webhooks.

#### What is the problem?

---

I created a job in jenkins which I can successfuly trigger by url.

When I'm triggering the same job from bitbucket's webhook, I get the error: `Problem accessing /job/projecty_ci/build. Reason: No valid crumb was included in the request`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Try to generate a CSRF token for use in your in your API requests.

- GOTO: Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security and enable
  Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits.
- Select Default Crumb Issuer from Crumb Algorithm and save to apply
  changes and enable.

[Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection)

You can get the crumb by calling the jenkins api and using it in your URL.

*For curl/wget you can obtain the header needed in the request from the URL JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml (or .../api/json). Something like this:*

```
wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user USERNAME --password PASSWORD --output-document - \
'JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
```

This will print something like ".crumb:1234abcd", which you should add to the subsequent request.

---

**Administer a Build**

**NOTE:** To prevent CSRF, Jenkins require POST requests to include a crumb, which is specific to each user. The command to obtain the crumb is:

```
SERVER=http://localhost:8080
    CRUMB=$(curl --user $USER:$APITOKEN \
        $SERVER/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat\(//crumbRequestField,%22:%22,//crumb\))
```

**Start a build**

```
$ curl -H ".crumb:<crumb_string>" -X POST http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/build --user <user_name>:<api_token>
```

Comment: How to pass this via bitbucket hooks?

Comment: You would need to setup the webhook in bitbucket to trigger the post call to Jenkins. Try this document- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html

Comment: I have created webhook successfully, my curl post request is triggering the build fine having crumb data. But not finding a way to pass via get url of webhook :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416925/how-to-pass-crumb-info-via-bitbucket-hook-to-jenkins

Comment: The setting name is `CSRF Protection` as of May 2021 and the checkbox you want to set is called `Enable proxy compatibility`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have link I can use to update answer with? Or can you add update?

Comment: Default Crumb is preselected anyways

Answer (score 0):

I may not be directly solving your issue here but wanted to share that we have managed to trigger a Jenkins job successfully by following the instructions on https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226568007-How-to-Trigger-Non-Multibranch-Jobs-from-BitBucket-Server-

The plugin that we use on BitBucket server is https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nerdwin15.stash-stash-webhook-jenkins/server/overview

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I can't use any plugings inside bitbucket. So must implement the communicating by my self.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late here, I was facing the same problem and I configured the webhook URL like this below to work for me:

http://jenkins-username:jenkins-password@jenkins-url:5555/job/job-name/build?crumb=crumb_token.

**Ref Question:** [How to pass crumb info via bitbucket-hook to jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416925/how-to-pass-crumb-info-via-bitbucket-hook-to-jenkins)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is this still working ? I'm not able to perform a webhook without having a "403 No valid crumb was included in the request". I'm with Jenkins 2.235. 5and BitBucket v5.13.1.

Comment: Have tried . still getting same error  "403 No valid crumb was included in the request".

Answer (score 0):

With my Jenkins version `2.365` , and with the help of previous answers, I have created the request as follow, and it worked fine.

*The URL you put in Bitbucket web hook URL field will be as follow:*

```
http://<jenkins-user>:API_TOKEN@<jenkins-url>:<jenkins-port>/job/<jenkins-job-id>/build
```

**Generate API token from Jenkins**

- In Jenkins click on the user name upper right -> Configure
- Go to API Token section and generate API_TOKEN as shown below
  [image]
- Copy this key, you need to use it in the request (replace in API_TOKEN field above)

Answer (score 0):

I found this error differently.

**Scenario:**

I have bitbucket repo which actually trigger jenkins pipeline in case of push, pull, Pull request creation and Pull Request merge.

**Solution**
First step i created Personal Access Token in Jenkins
Configure -> API Token (Create New API Token)

Now goto Bitbucket Repository

Repository Settings -> Webhooks -> Repository hooks (Create a new Hook)

In the Hook we need to pass Jenkins Personal Access Token and along with Username

**Below is the sample URL.**

http://JenkinsUser:JenkinsPersonalAccessToken@Jenkins.localhost.com:8080/job/dockerapi-pipeline/build?token=PipelineToken

Answer (score 0):

You can disable CSRF and use an API token instead for authentication.

1. Go to /manage/script and run

> hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION=true

2. Generate an API token by

> Manage Jenkins > Manage Users > Add new token

3. Bitbucket webhook URL should look like this

> https://admin:{your-newly-generated-jenkins-token}@{your jenkin server
> ip address}/job/{jenkins_job_id}/build/

**Don't forget to add the forward slash at the end of the URL*